# Can we use external user input as filters in data studio for google analytics data source

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I'm creating a report in google data studio using google analytics data source. Now i want to use the filers in the page setting as an external input. So user can input the filter string and can see the data. Somehow i need to pass the string to the data studio so the report will be generated on the basis of that filter.

I appreciate any small help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If i were you I would make the input in Google Sheets and direct string to there.

NExt step is link the string to Google Datastudio via "Add data". Even if it is only one cell it should work. Now you can try to somehow make the filter auto select this data and there you go.